# VBA right way of clearing/resetting an excel document?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

So, I found a bit of code on a website a few weeks ago that worked perfectly for what I need but I am just wondering what exactly the following bit of code does because to me it makes more sense to clear the document using `MainSheet1.Cells.Clear` and then just do a series of `Range("Z1").Value = "Group"` for example

Why has this person chose to make an array and fill it in that way...?

```
Sub CLEAR_DOCUMENT()

    '
    Dim headers(1 To 4, 1 To 15) As Variant

    MainSheet1.Cells.Clear

    headers(4, 1) = "Group"
    headers(4, 2) = "Look"
    headers(4, 3) = "Time"
    headers(4, 4) = "Tie"
    headers(4, 5) = "Type"
    headers(4, 6) = "Name"
    headers(4, 7) = "Num"
    headers(1, 8) = "School 2"
    headers(1, 9) = "Group 2"
    headers(2, 8) = "*"
    headers(2, 9) = ">0"
    headers(1, 11) = "Time"
    headers(1, 12) = "Language"
    headers(1, 13) = "School 1"
    headers(1, 14) = "Age"
    headers(1, 15) = "Eng"

    MainSheet1.Range("Z1:AN4").Value = headers

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: how abt checking with the author of the code. As long as what you've done works fine, stick to it.

Comment: @hnk The author hadn't been on the site for 2 years and I can't find where I downloaded it from...

Comment: Performance reasons, mainly. If you put data in a variant and then make `Range = Variant` it's a lot faster than individually setting cells.

Comment: because a single statement writing to the worksheet is faster than 17 (or 100, or 1000...) statements writing to the worksheet.  Working with arrays in memory is faster than writing directly to the sheet, so populate the array,a nd then write the entire array to the sheet in one statement, instead of multiple statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you posted is very very slightly faster than filling the cells one at a time.